# How to create a mountable file system?

Tags: filesystems

This is just for self-study purpose.

In Windows, Linux or Mac, we can mount many kinds of file system (including SAMBA, Google drive file system, etc) and access them as if there were ordinary files and folders in the hard disk. How to create such file system? I am referring to the file system itself, not to the server where the files are stored.

I prefer if the tutorial is for Mac or Linux (I would guess that the technique will be OS dependent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not as trivial as you might think.

I had to do this some time ago. What I did was to integrate a TCP/IP-based file server into my program and used the network file system functionality of the OS.

Today the "FUSE" project is available for Linux (and as far as I understand correctly) for MacOS X (the last one seems to be named "MacFUSE").

The "FUSE" project provides you a special API which allows you to create a mountable file system...

You install "FUSE" and you can write programs that provide file systems to the OS.

Comment: Yes, I am aware it is not straight forward :) May I know what library/framework you used when you integrated your TCP/IP file server?

In my work place, I have a web-based file storage (I have access to its source code). But it starts to get irritating whenever I want to download or upload large number of files. So I want to explore using file system (I already have the code to simulate login, session keeping, etc). Our development (virtual) machine is Linux, but most of my colleagues often bring their own Mac to work (I also bring my own Mac to work)

Comment: On Mac it's OSXFUSE, which has replaced MacFuse.